# Add a background colour to a MediaComposition

Tags: c#, video, uwp, windows-10-desktop

I'm trying to create a MediaComposition.  I have succeeded in combining multiple png images into a single video; however, the files that's created has a black background.  At first I thought this might be because the files were png files, but the same bevaviour occurs for jpgs.  The following is how I'm saving the image:

```
public async Task<bool> Save(InkCanvas canvas, StorageFile file)
{

    if (canvas != null && canvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes().Count > 0)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                await canvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.SaveAsync(stream);
            }
        }
        Clear(canvas);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It saves the image fine, but the background is alpha.  What this means is that when I try and chain these together into a media composition, there is no background, and it renders as black.  I have tried using overlays when creating the MediaComposition to correct this:

```
MediaClip overlayVideoClip = MediaClip.CreateFromColor(Colors.White, new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));
MediaOverlay mo = new MediaOverlay(overlayVideoClip);
MediaOverlayLayer mol = new MediaOverlayLayer();
mol.Overlays.Add(mo);

composition.OverlayLayers.Add(mol);
```

But to no avail.  My suspicion is that I'm misunderstanding the meaning of the term overlay in this case.  So, my questions are: is it possible to overlay the video at composition time and, if so, how?  Alternatively, if this needs to be done in the image itself, how can I save the image with a background?

EDIT:

I've made progress (?) with this; the following compiles and runs, but creates a solid black image:

```
    public async Task TestSave(InkCanvas canvas, StorageFile file)
    {
        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = 
           new RenderTargetBitmap();
        PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        await rtb.RenderAsync(canvas);
        var pixelBuffer = await rtb.GetPixelsAsync();

        using (IRandomAccessStream stream = 
             await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {                
            BitmapEncoder encoder = 
                 await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);

            encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
                (uint)rtb.PixelWidth,
                (uint)rtb.PixelHeight,
                96d, 96d,
                pixelBuffer.ToArray());

            await encoder.FlushAsync();                
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153880/how-to-render-inkcanvas-to-an-image-in-uwp-windows-10-application) answer, which sort of solves the problem by using the Win2D library; although it doesn't address my actual issue, it lets me let around it.  Hopefully there is a better solution out there.

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. Just save the image with no alpha background?

Comment: Either save the image with a background, or layer the background in at the time of creating the video file (currently using MediaComposition)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing I understand about this is you are trying to save an image with a background. My suggestion to solve this is to save the transparent image you have to something like

```
<StackPanel x:Name="AreaWhichWillBeSavedToImage" Background=*Some Color*>
  <Image x:Name="theAlphaImage">
</StackPanel>
```

Now if you don't want the image to display on your GUI just set it to Hidden.

Then you can save the file with the color background of your choice.

```
var bitmap = await SaveToFileAsync(AreaWhichWillBeSavedToImage, await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path + @"someimage.jpg"));

  async Task<RenderTargetBitmap> SaveToFileAsync(FrameworkElement uielement, StorageFile file)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            CachedFileManager.DeferUpdates(file);

            Guid encoderId = GetBitmapEncoder(file.FileType);

            try
            {
                using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                {
                    return await CaptureToStreamAsync(uielement, stream, encoderId);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //DisplayMessage(ex.Message);
            }

            var status = await CachedFileManager.CompleteUpdatesAsync(file);
        }

        return null;
    }

    async Task<RenderTargetBitmap> CaptureToStreamAsync(FrameworkElement uielement, IRandomAccessStream stream, Guid encoderId)
    {
        try
        {
            var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
            await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(uielement);

            var pixels = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

            var logicalDpi = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi;
            var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(encoderId, stream);
            encoder.SetPixelData(
                BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
                (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
                logicalDpi,
                logicalDpi,
                pixels.ToArray());

            await encoder.FlushAsync();

            return renderTargetBitmap;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //DisplayMessage(ex.Message);
        }

        return null;
    }

    Guid GetBitmapEncoder(string fileType)
    {
        Guid encoderId = BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId;
        switch (fileType)
        {
            case ".bmp":
                encoderId = BitmapEncoder.BmpEncoderId;
                break;
            case ".gif":
                encoderId = BitmapEncoder.GifEncoderId;
                break;
            case ".png":
                encoderId = BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId;
                break;
            case ".tif":
                encoderId = BitmapEncoder.TiffEncoderId;
                break;
        }

        return encoderId;
    }
```

Comment: Save InkCanvas Image as theAlphaImage's ImageSource, then it works

Comment: If you mean like this: <Image x:Name="theAlphaImage" Source="{Binding ElementName=myInkCanvas}"> then it doesn't seem to work

Comment: You are saving your inkCanvas to a IRandomAccessStream. That stream is easily converted into a Render Bitmap or WritableBitmap etc. Once you convert it to a type of bitmap, you can set the image source to the bitmap

Comment: Whilst this does work (many thanks), the image only saves when it is visible in the visual tree.  Otherwise, it just saves as blank.