# How to draw using finger over any shape or image in uwp

Tags: xaml, uwp

I'm trying to draw using finger on any image or any shape or inside a particular shape eg rectangle. How to do that
Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that purpose [the InkCanvas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn858535) is designed. You can surely find [tutorials](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/07/24/uwp-new-controls-part-4-inking/) and some [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/pen-and-stylus-interactions) about this. Even [other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32153880/2681948).